# svn commit to trigger google analytics annotation?

Tags: svn, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I was wondering if there is a way to create a script that is triggered by an SVN commit, and which would add an annotation in a google analytics profile?

This would be handy is something changes in a web app, which will have impact in the analytics of the app eventually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is currently no way to create annotations via either of the Google Analytics APIs (Data Export API and Management API). Both APIs are currently read-only only for all operations.

There is a fairly popular (<strike>95</strike>,<strike>129</strike>,<strike>157</strike>,<strike>176</strike>,<strike>189</strike>, <strike>253</strike>, 383 supporters) feature request, "[Add Annotations update API](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=53&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)" on the official Google Analytics issues page, but there's no known progress on this. It appears the only way to create annotations at the moment is manually, from within the Google Analytics account.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. it's super lame that they don't have this- i am sure it would make the life of thousands of webmasters and developers easier. are there other analytics packages that do support something like this? maybe clicky?